# Getting Sub-dependencies in a pnpm Deployment Without Bundling

Tags: node.js, node-modules, pnpm

We're using `pnpm` now in our monorepo. Everything is working great when running locally. Everything is working great when deploying *for packages that are bundled*.

For the couple Node Express applications that we do *not* bundle, our deployment process ZIPs those package folders which breaks the symbolic link to the `pnpm` store in the root workspace. Unfortunately, this causes the dependencies of these applications to lose access to all of their subdependencies.

What I would like is for the `node_modules` in each of the applications that I specify to have a flat `node_modules` structure, without having to hoist every package to the root workspace's `node_modules`, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Is it possible to tell `pnpm` to install the `node_modules` *for a particular package* in a flat structure, including all subdependencies?

I have tried almost every configuration option from the `pnpm` documentation, but none seems to give the desired result. I am explicitly *not* looking to hoist all of the packages to the root workspace's `node_modules`, which is easily accomplished.